# Scala List with type parameter

Tags: scala

I had a problem coding a function called **head**, that basically replace the head elements with another for the List invoking it:

```
List(1,2,3,4).head(4) // List(4,2,3,4)
```

The code is obviously useless, I was just trying to have fun with Scala. This is the code:

```
sealed trait List[+A]{
  def tail():List[A]
  def head[A](x:A):List[A]
}

object Nil extends List[Nothing]{
  def tail() = throw new Exception("Nil couldn't has tail")
  def head[A](x:A): List[A] = List(x)
}

case class Cons[+A](x :A, xs: List[A]) extends List[A]{
  def tail():List[A] = xs
  def head[A](a:A): List[A] = Cons(a,xs)
}

object List{
  def apply[A](as:A*):List[A] = {
    if (as.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(as.head,apply(as.tail: _*))
  }
}

Cons(1,Cons(2,Nil)) == List(1,2)
Cons(1,Cons(2,Cons(3,Cons(4,Nil)))).tail()
List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).tail()
List(1,2,3,4).head(4)
```

It doesn't not compile and I have this error:

```
Error:(11, 39) type mismatch;
found   : A$A318.this.List[A(in class Cons)]
required: A$A318.this.List[A(in method head)]
 def head[A](a:A): List[A] = Cons(a,xs)
```

Could you explain why, please?

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that your `head` method is taking another type `A`, therefore inside that scope the compiler takes those `A`s as different, i.e., the `A` defined in the trait is shadowed by the `A` in `head[A]`.

Also, your `head` method is taking a covariant element of type `A` in a contravariant position, so you can't define `head` as such.

What you can do is defining your `head` as:

```
def head[B >: A](x: B): List[B]
```

Hence, you get:

```
object S {
    sealed trait List[+A] {
        def tail(): List[A]
        def head[B >: A](x: B): List[B]
    }

    case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
        def tail() = throw new Exception("Nil doesn't have a tail")
        def head[B >: Nothing](x: B): List[B] = Cons(x, Nil)
    }

    case class Cons[+A](x: A, xs: List[A]) extends List[A] {
      def tail(): List[A] = xs
      def head[B >: A](a: B): List[B] = Cons(a, xs)
    }

    object List {
      def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] = {
        if (as.isEmpty) Nil
        else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
      }
    }
}
```

Testing this on the REPL:

```
scala> :load test.scala
Loading test.scala...
defined object S

scala> import S._
import S._

scala> Nil.head(1)
res0: S.List[Int] = Cons(1,Nil)

scala> Cons(1, Nil).head(4)
res1: S.List[Int] = Cons(4,Nil)
```

Comment: So basically with my type parameter A inside head method, I'm like  shadowing the original type parameter A used when I defined my class, right?

Comment: That's right. The `A` in the `head` method shadows the `A` in the trait.

Answer (score 1):

You method head does not need a type parameter, since you already have one defined in the class definition and that is exactly the type you want head to receive (if you want head to create a list of the same type of the original).

The error you get is because A is two different types in the context of the method head (the one from the method and the other from the class).

The definition for head should be:

```
def head(x:A):List[A]
```

Comment: No, this isn't correct. `A` is covariant and you are putting it in a contravariant position.